# How to locate and click "speed test" link on netflix using selenium in python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I'm a complete beginner with selenium, sorry if the question is dumb (it is dumb):)
I need to find Speed test link on https://www.netflix.com/ and then click it.

i've tried searching by text and some other options. But nothing seems to work, I don't know why.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keysfrom selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Speed test")
elem.click()
```

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sign in"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` with following xpath.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/")
elem = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@data-uia='data-uia-footer-label'][contains(.,'Speed Test')]")))
elem.click()
```

Browser snapshot:

[image]

To added to this answer you need to use `WebDriverWait` and then click on the element `Show more info`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/")
elem = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@data-uia='data-uia-footer-label'][contains(.,'Speed Test')]")))
elem.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(.,'Show more info' )]"))).click()
```

Answer (score 2):

The element with text as **Speed Test** is out ofthe [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element to be clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='footer-link']/span[text()='Speed Test']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```